# How to change everyone clientIP in ansible?

Tags: sed, ansible

I'm still learning Ansible ...
Want to replce ip address in  Ansible by client IP

hosts:

```
[servers]
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.18
192.168.0.19
192.168.0.23
192.168.0.129
192.168.0.130
192.168.0.149
```

server.yml

```
---
- name: Create update alive crontab
hosts: servers
become: true
tasks:
- name: a crontab job
  cron:
      minute="0"
      job="http://xx.xx.xx.xx/alive.php?ip=clientIP"
```

How to change everyone clientIP in server.yml ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the variable **ansible_host**

> job="http://xx.xx.xx.xx/alive.php?ip={{ ansible_host }}"

See example:

```
# ansible -m debug -a 'msg="{{ ansible_host }}"' localhost
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": "127.0.0.1"
}
```